# Rails - Is it a correct way to use polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, has-many, polymorphic-associations

here come a newbie of Rails.

Currently, I am trying to make somehow a "decision game" using rails, which the `Game` is being played by making some decisions and click next round and come to some results. And I have made it already.

However, I am trying to add a mini game mode to this game, so I would like to have `Routine Game` and `Mini Game` for the players. The differences of these two modes are that `Routine Game` would have number of rounds and different missions to achieve, where `Mini Game` mode would just have one round and one mission to achieve. And, a player only has one `Routine Game`, but many `Mini Game`

So I thought it should be somehow an inheritance setting. After reading some documentation and tutorial online, I found the "magical" polymorphic association in rails. I am thinking of implementing it by the following setting (simplified), but felt that the polymorphic doesn't make sense for me. Am I using polymorphic in a correct condition and a correct way?

```
class Game
    belongs_to :mode, polymorphic: true
end

class RoutineGame
    has_one :game, as: :mode
    belongs_to :user
end

class MiniGame
    has_one :game, as: :mode
    belongs_to :user
end

class User
    has_one :routine_game
    has_many :mini_games
end
```

Thanks for reading and appreciate any ideas.